# Error on Button clicked again Simple if then else statment ( working correctly for first time )

Tags: java

i am new to android and java , 
below is a simple code of comparing the value which i am getting from edit text ( type number ) and getting it compare it with an amount suppose 14000,  but when i am running this app its crashing if the condition is true i.e final_salary > 14000 if true then its not updating the textview tv to r1 value which is 14000 and application getting crashed,

one more request if some one can guide me how to debug this or catch this error point to get it correct, i am coming from VB platform and debugging was relatively ( my personal opinion ) was easy then eclipse... !!

```
Following is the dump from log cat ?

08-01 18:46:54.354: W/ResourceType(2382): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00003872
08-01 18:46:54.354: D/AndroidRuntime(2382): Shutting down VM
08-01 18:46:54.354: W/dalvikvm(2382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4dd9b20)
08-01 18:46:54.362: D/dalvikvm(2382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 118K, 5% free 3967K/4156K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382): Process: com.example.taxcalculator, PID: 2382
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3872
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at com.example.taxcalculator.MainActivity.a(MainActivity.java:28)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at com.example.taxcalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-01 18:46:54.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2382):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 18:47:01.806: I/Process(2382): Sending signal. PID: 2382 SIG: 9
```

==============

```
    public void a() {

    EditText getsal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_salary);
    String getsal_temp= getsal.getText().toString();
    int final_salary=Integer.parseInt(getsal_temp);
    int r1;
    if  (final_salary  > 14000)    

        {

            r1= final_salary;
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_slab1);
            tv.setText(r1);

        }

    else 

    {   
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_slab1);
        tv.setText("NOT"); 

    }

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cal_tax);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            a();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set an Integer as text for a TextView. But because there is a method `TextView.setText(int ResourceId)` the compiler thinks you are using this one since your param is an integer. When the framework tries to find this StringResource, it fails and throws an Exception. Use `tv.setText(r1+"")` or `tv.setText(String.vlaueOf(r1));`. Both will cast the integer to a string, but i'd recomend the second one, cause the first one is kind of bad practice.